# Does premake support thread-sanitizer builds?

Tags: c++, address-sanitizer, premake, thread-sanitizer

Building for thread sanitizer is a simple flag in gcc invokation:

```
-fsanitize=thread
```

Yet when looking at [sanitizer support in premake](https://premake.github.io/docs/sanitize/) I only see the options "Address" and "Fuzzer".

- Is there an "official" way to build with thread sanitizer using premake?
- If not, where do I have to specify my `-fsanitize=thread` flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are still [`buildoptions`](https://premake.github.io/docs/buildoptions/)/[linkoptions](https://premake.github.io/docs/linkoptions/)

so

```lua
filter "toolset:gcc or toolset:clang"
    buildoptions{"-fsanitize=thread"}
    linkoptions{"-fsanitize=thread"}
filter {}
```

Comment: will have to verify this and give feedback. Currently stuck with devops tasks but hopefully tomorrow I'll get to check it and accept the answer (just an fyi cause you took the time to answer)